# RestKit .20 CoreData postObject EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, restkit, restkit-0.20

I'm attempting to use RestKit to handle posting an updated `User` object to my remote web service.

Currently my `GET` requests seem to be working fine but I'm having issues using 
`[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] postObject:updatedUser path:@"path" parameters:nil success:nil failure:nil];`

Invoking this method is throwing a `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` exception.

My mappings are set up as follows, I believe I have both the `RKRequestDescriptor` and `RKResponseDescriptor`'s.

User Response Mapping:

```
RKEntityMapping * userMapping =
[RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:NSStringFromClass([User class])
inManagedObjectStore:[manager managedObjectStore]];
```

….Setup mapping (I excluded a relationship mapping on this object)

```
[manager addResponseDescriptorsFromArray:@[
        [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:userMapping
                                                     method:RKRequestMethodGET
                                                pathPattern:nil 
                                                    keyPath:@"currentUser"
                                                statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)]]]
```

Request mapping:

```
[manager addRequestDescriptorsFromArray:@[
        [RKRequestDescriptor requestDescriptorWithMapping:[userMapping inverseMapping]
                                              objectClass:[User class]
                                              rootKeyPath:nil
                                                   method:RKRequestMethodPOST]]];
```

The mappings seem to set up fine, the `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` exception is thrown when I call `postObject`

The test method looks like this, `_updatedUser` is a CoreData object fetched using `[RKObjectManager sharedManager] getObjectsAtPath:…`

```
-(void) doPost{
   //this user is a CoreData object fetched using 
    [_updatedUser setBio:@"This is an update!"];

    RKObjectManager * objectManager = [RKObjectManager sharedManager];
    [objectManager postObject:_updatedUser
                         path:@"update/user"
                   parameters:nil
                      success:…
                      failure:…];

  }
```

I've attempted using `NSZombies` to find the cause of this but I have't had much luck.

From what I can tell the start of the issue seems to be coming from `RKObjectParameterization`'s  `-[RKObjectParameterization mappingOperation:didSetValue:forKeyPath:usingMapping:]` where it looks like everything passed into the method is nil or an empty string.

Thanks!

Comment: Log `_updatedUser` before the call, what does it output? Turn on trace logging, does it say anything interesting?

Comment: _updatedUser looks, as far as I can tell, like the updated CoreData object. The correct data looks to be in place

Comment: Interesting enough, turning on Trace seems to show some kind of infinite loop

Comment: Wain, logging fixed my issue. I had what seems like a circular refrence between relationship mappings

Comment: Please consider adding your own answer to explain the issue and resolution if you think it might help other people in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Much thanks to Wain, after spending way too much time on this the error became instantly apparent after I turned on logging:

```
RKLogConfigureByName("RestKit", RKLogLevelWarning);
RKLogConfigureByName("RestKit/ObjectMapping", RKLogLevelTrace);
RKLogConfigureByName("RestKit/Network", RKLogLevelTrace);
```

It turns out I had a circular reference between mapped objects.

I have a one to one relationship where a `User` contains a `UserProfile`

I incorrectly set up a bidirectional relationship mapping between `User` and `UserProfile`

```
[userProfileMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping
                  relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"user"
                                       toKeyPath:@"user" 
                                     withMapping:userMapping]];

[userMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping  relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"userProfile"
                 toKeyPath:@"userProfile"
               withMapping:userProfileMapping]];
```

It looks like my endless loop was caused by userProfileMapping

Thanks Wain, logging lesson learned.